# cant locate and install libjpeg.so.8 in my github actions

Tags: ubuntu, github-actions, libjpeg, libjpeg-turbo

I want to use libjpeg.so.8 in my github actions workflow, but can't. I've tried installing libjpeg0 but im unable to. Maybe you could know any way around this? I've also tried installing libjpeg-turbo8 but get error: libjpeg-turbo8. I tried both ubunutu-latests and ubunutu-20.04

Ive tried using ubuntu-latest and ubuntu-20.04. Tried installing libjpeg8, libjpeg-turbo8, libjpeg62-turbo, libjpeg62-turbo-dev. Non of these work, either github actions is unable to install it: has no installation candidate; or installed package does not have libjpeg.so.8 in it.

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=kinetic&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libjpeg-turbo8&searchon=names reports that only `kinetic`, 22.10, has the package. The file list reports that there is indeed a `libjpeg.so.8` in it. Is the "latest" 22.10? Try making the workflow run `lsb_release -a` and check its output.

Comment: And in case you are hoping for anything useful in `libjpeg.so.8` from turbo: don't. The turbo fork explicitly does not include the non-standard and barely interoperable features IJG decided to add -- the features the lib version got bumped to 8 for. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libjpeg#Change_in_IJG_leadership for the drama.